# How to extract only the digits and print as a string

Tags: python-3.x

Here I want to extract 011700 (these are 6 digit codes) which I want to extract without the semi-colon and later I will use a dict for a value against it.

How do I extract only 011700 (or 6 digit number from that line)?
And how to print it as a 6 digit number - instead of printing it like `['011700']`?

Thanks.

```
import re
        
line = "N    011700;      3;20:34:00:02:ac:07:e9:d5;2f:f7:00:02:ac:07:e9:d5; 3333"
line_list = line.split()
print(line_list)
result = (re.findall('\\d+', line))
print(result)
```

Comment: If it's always same length and same position: `print(line[5:11])`

Comment: `(\d{6})` is the pattern you want. But as Johnny says, if these strings are always consistent, you might as well just slice out the number you want instead of using regex.

Comment: wow!! got it.. :)  yes it is always at the second spot (index 1) Also, I would like to know -- result = (re.findall('\d+', line_list[1]))
print(result) ... this prints the result as ['011700'] how to print this as 011700 instead of the the brackets. ?

Comment: @redpy Remember, the `findall` method returns a list of all possible results. If you want the first (and in this case only) result, then you'd `print(result[0])`. Or if you want result to be just the number, then change your line to `result = (re.findall('\\d+', line))[0]`

Comment: Thank you Johnny, Blorgon and Nat..all this  really helped me :) great mentors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would go about modifying your current code.
First, I would specify that you are trying to split the string by semicolons, by changing your split line to:

```
line_list = line.split(";")
```

Then I would trim off any whitespace, which you could do with a second line like:

```
line_list = [l.strip() for l in line_list]
```

(or by combining them like)

```
line_list = [l.strip() for l in line.split(";")]
```

Then I would simply loop through the list like so:

```
for l in line_list:
    if len(l) == 6:
        result = l
        break
```

And if you want the result to be the actual number and not just a string of the number, change the line to:

```
result = int(l)
```

Altogether that would look like this:

```
line = "N    011700;      3;20:34:00:02:ac:07:e9:d5;2f:f7:00:02:ac:07:e9:d5; 3333"
line_list = [l.strip() for l in line.split(";")]
for l in line_list:
    if len(l) == 6:
        result = int(l)
        break
print(line_list)
print(result)
```

Result now contains the string of the first six-digit number found in your original string.